# Convert C# code to PL/SQL code

Tags: c#, plsql

I have code written in C# and need to convert to PL/SQL code.
Code C#:

```
long n1=563272302, n2=369098752;

n1 ^= 0x000000004892011bL ^ n2;
```

Result after operation is:

```
n1=2130762613
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

http://www.oracledba.co.uk/tips/bitwise_ops.htm

you find how to add a bitwise XOR function to PL/SQL.

With this function it should be (untested):

```
Set n1 = bitxor(n1, bitxor(0x4892011b,n2))
```